# Express.js req.body is returning nothing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am learning node and express to create an api for an angular app I will be creating.

When I try and post something the `req.body` seems to be blank.

This is my server.js file

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  router = require('./api'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_db');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', router);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/index.jade');
});

app.listen(3001, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 3001');
});
```

and this is my api/index.js file:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    Todo = require('../models/todo'),
    router = express.Router();

router.get('/todos', function(req, res) {
  Todo.find({}, function(err, todos) {
    if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    res.json({todos: todos});
  });
});

router.post('/todos', function(req, res) {
  var todo = req.body;
  res.json({todo: todo});
});


module.exports = router;
```

when I use postman to post this to `http://localhost:3001/api/todos`:

```
{
    'name': 'Walk the Dog',
    'completed': false
}
```

my response is:

```
{
  "todo": {}
}
```

I can't see why this would be blank, any help is appreciated.

***UPDATE***

Turns out I was posting `text` in postman instead of `JSON`.

Comment: I haven't set angular up yet, I am doing the API first, I was posting using an app called postman. Turns out It was my fault, I was posting `text` instead of `JSON` I will update my question.

Comment: Are you sending as `application/json` from postman? Or as form encoded which is default?

Comment: Did you check if you receive it on server? I mean console.log that?

Answer (score 0):

use this in your server.js file

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```